# I keep on receiving a layout error when I add a new cell to a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to add data from one view controller to a collection view controller which adds an element to the datasource array and then adds a cell to the collection view.

`prepareforsegue` in previous `ViewController`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "unwindToCollectionView"{
        let CVC = segue.destination as! CollectionViewController
        if let image = image{
        CVC.images.insert(imagePost(image:image), at: 0)
            print("Image is not nil")
        }
        let index = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        //CVC.collectionView?.reloadData()

        CVC.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        CVC.collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()
        CVC.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [index])
        //CVC.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [index])
        print("In prepare for segue: \(CVC.images.count)")
    }
}
```

`collectionViewController` `cellForItemAt`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    // Configure the cell
    cell.cellImageView.image = images[indexPath.row].image

    cell.cellImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width-1)/2, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width-1)/2)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    cell.cellImageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat((cell.cellImageView.frame.width)/2)
    return cell
}
```

Error received:

> 2018-01-25 11:43:16.228902-0500 CAR+CV(1.0)Server[4182:1181750] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot set the layout [] for [; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, -88}; contentSize: {375, 573}; adjustedContentInset: {88, 0, 83, 0}> collection view layout: ] during an update.

Comment: Why are you calling `invalidateLayout`, `layoutIfNeeded`, and `insertItems` in `prepareForSegue`? Also I don't think you should be setting the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath`… Why don't you use the methods in the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol?

Comment: @shim where should `insertItems` be called if not in the `prepareForSegue` when I tried deleting it and calling it inside of `viewDidLoad` of the `collectionViewController` I received errors regarding the indexing.

Comment: Maybe you're misinterpreting the purpose of `insertItems`. You just need to set up `cellForItemAt` and `numberOfItemsInSection` and the collection view handles inserting the items itself. `insertItems` is mostly for when you need to show a new item being added — and there has to be a corresponding change in the data source of the collection view.

Comment: @shim I am passing an array with an added item after the segue. When I don't call `insertItems` in the `prepareForSegue` the new cell is not being generated in the collectionView

Answer (score 1):

Very wrong way to do this...

First, set your `collectionViewLayout` in `viewDidLoad()`

Next, in `prepareForSegue`, you want to modify the collection view's Data, not the collection view itself.

So...

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "unwindToCollectionView"{
        let CVC = segue.destination as! CollectionViewController
        if let image = image {
            // add the image to the CollectionViewController's data 
            CVC.images.insert(imagePost(image:image), at: 0)
            print("Image is not nil")
        }
        print("In prepare for segue: \(CVC.images.count)")
    }
}
```

Then, your collection view's `cellForItemAt` is simply:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell
    cell.cellImageView.image = images[indexPath.row].image

    // don't do this here...
    // cell.cellImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    // cell.cellImageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat((cell.cellImageView.frame.width)/2)

    return cell
}
```

---

**Edit:** as a side note, setting `.cornerRadius` should not be done in `cellForItemAt` either, as the cell will not be laid-out yet. Much better to subclass `UIImageView` and set the `.cornerRadius` in `layoutSubviews()`

---

**Edit 2:**

```
class RoundImageView: UIImageView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2.0

    }

}
```

Just set the Class of your current `UIImageView` to `RoundImageView`.

*"where do I call insertItems(at:[index])"*

You don't need to do that. When your segue moves to the view controller, your collection view will reload and the image you just inserted into your `images` array will become the first cell. I notice your segue identifier is `"unwindToCollectionView"` - so if your collection view does **not** automatically reload, add this to the VC holding the collection view:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response it is very helpful. I have moved the layout to `viewDidLoad` and removed everything from `prepareForSegue` besides updating the array in the collectionViewController. But where do I call `insertItems(at:[index])` so that the `collectionView` adds a new cell for the new element in the array. And what would not setting the `cornerRadius` in `cellForItemAt` look like would I have to override `layoutSubviews`

Comment: @user372382 - see **Edit 2** in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your Edit it was very helpful the code now works. Would it be possible to use `collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath])` instead of `collectionView.reloadData()`?

Comment: Think about it Logically... Say your collection view looks like this: `A | B | C | D` (your `images` array)... you are inserting `Z` at position `0` in the array. If you only do `.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath])`, your collection view would look like this: `Z | B | C | D`. Is that your desired goal? Or do you want the result to be `Z | A | B | C | D`? I suspect the latter, in which case you want `.reloadData()`.